# jQuery moving a control while move the mouse on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div containing a time range. I also have a scroll for the div when moving the mouse. What I am trying to move the time control along with the scroll, while the mouse is moving on the time range.The issue is time control does not move according to mouse move.

Here is what I did:

```js
$('#timeTable').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var xPrev = 600;
  var inc = 0;
  var position = $('#nowTime').offset().left;
  var leftOffset = $(this).offset().left;
  if (xPrev < e.pageX) {
    inc = -255;
  }
  $('#timeTableInner').css('left', -e.clientX + leftOffset + inc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<time id="nowTime">10:00</time>
<div id="timeTable">
  <div id="timeTableInner">
 <ul id="timeText">
     <li class="t0000"><span class="hourText">0:00</span></li>
     <li class="t0015">&nbsp;</li>
     <li class="t0030">&nbsp;</li>
         ------------
      <li class="t2400"><span class="hourText">24:00</span></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the code. And what seems to be the issue , You haven't asked a question.

Comment: What's the problem that you are facing now?

Comment: Attribute `position` of `timeTableInner` is `absolute`??

Comment: yes.position is absolute

Comment: Then did you check console whether `mousemove` works well or not?

Comment: mouse move is working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this please.

Is this what you want?

[check my updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/5j3vwsu0/3/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<time id="nowTime">10:00</time>
<div id="timeTable">
    <div id="timeTableInner">
        <ul id="timeText">
            <li class="t0000"><span class="hourText">0:00</span></li>
            <li class="t0015">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="t0030">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="t2400"><span class="hourText">24:00</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can the nowTime element can be moved with a different css.?

Comment: @David I've updated. what you mean `different css`??

Comment: what i mean is nowTime will be outside timeTable.So on mousemove can we set the nowTime to be moving along with time.

Comment: @David sure we can. No matter where element is in, if you give `id` or `class` to what you want to cook, you can handle that absolutely.